# Indexing columns that exists in OR clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with primary key, and two foreign keys, where both allows NULLS.

When I create indexes separately for each two columns, query running about 2-3 seconds and return around 300000 rows.

When I create composite non-clustered index for that two columns, query running around 10 minutes for same number of rows.

It's important to notice that two columns appear in WHERE condition and works with OR clause, like this:

```
Select 
    SomeColumn
From
    SomeTable
Where 
    FirstColumn = x OR SecondColumn = x
```

Platform on which query was executed is SQL 2008 R2.

Why there is such a difference in execution time in that two cases?

Comment: Clustered index isn't composite, it contain one column and that is identity column of table, and hence, primary key. Other two columns create additionally two indexes, respectively, or one composite index, and that two column are those in WHERE filter.

Comment: show us execution plan, my guess is that one of the non clustered indexes has never been used, and in composite index you have chosen wrong column as first one , what is data selectivity on the first column in composite index - argh, sry for confusion . couldnt edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two separate indexes, and only those two columns are in the `WHERE` clause then the optimizer can use them both efficiently to determine the required rows (presumably an `INDEX SEEK`).

A composite index is not that good as composite indexes are first sorted on the first index column, then the second, and so on. So it's just useful for the first column in your `OR` condition, like you got. To determine the rows for the second column the optimizer would have to scan the complete table as it doesn't have suitable index.

If you got a large table with this scenario, then the single indexes will be usually faster for simple queries like you asked. It actually also depends on the selected columns, query complexity, covering indexes and so on.

I had this problem myself. See: [Query performance of combined index vs. multiple single indexes vs. fulltext index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/702469/44522) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

the point is , order of columns in indexes matter

```
create table #temp (col1 int, col2 int )
create nonclustered index index1 on #temp(col1, col2)
```

is not the same as

```
create nonclustered index index2 on #temp(col2, col1)
```

as in comment, post execution plan for the query

or change column order in composite index and rerun the query

as stated in comment, my guess is that when there are two non-clustered indexes - optymizer use one of them 
if you drop them and recreate as composite index with first column with low data selectivity the index wont be used , and query execution time will suffer

it would be much easier if you post the query